# Can one enable display-line-numbers in buffer's startup?

Tags: org-mode, line-numbers

How would one enable line numbers on a buffer basis? What I have in mind is a statement in the preamble of the buffer of this form:

```
#+STARTUP: [...(turn on line numbers)...]
```

Comment: add `display-line-numbers-mode` to the specific buffer’s hook?

Comment: @Shynur hasn't worked for me.

Comment: The `#+STARTUP:` syntax is Org mode specific: are you talking about Org mode files only or something more general? If more general. on what basis is one to decide whether `display-line-numbers-mode` should be turned on?

Comment: For an individual buffer, all you have to do is `M-x display-line-numbers-mode`. That toggles the mode on: if you do it again, it toggles it off.

Comment: @NickD `M-x ...` does not persist from one session to the next. Yes, org files.

Comment: Use the mode hook as @Shynur suggests then: `(with-eval-after-load 'org (add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'display-line-numbers-mode))`. Add that to your init file. That ensures that the hook will be modified only *after* the file `org.elc` or `org.el` is loaded: the hook variable is defined in that file and as you now know, the variable has to be defined before it can be modified.

Comment: @NickD "...as you now know, the variable has to be defined before it can be modified." You can set hook variables with `add-hook` without defining and/or setting them first. (The doc of `add-hook` clarifies that the value of the variable can be void.)

Comment: @NickD I don't even know what "buffer's hook" refers to.

Comment: @Erwann: "*what "buffer's hook" refers to.*" --- Any hook, as long as it will run when you open a new buffer.  (e.g., a buffer's major mode's hook)

Comment: @Erwann: I gave you a line of code to cut-and-paste (but as @Tobias points out it can be simplified: `add-hook` is careful to define the variable if it finds it undefined (but make sure to spell it correctly :-)  ) so you can leave out the `with-eval-after-load` part, although leaving it in does not hurt). You can just add then `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'display-line-numbers-mode)` to your init file, restart Emacs and you should be all set.

Comment: @NickD it seems that this instruction in the init file has the same effect as `'(global-display-line-numbers-mode t)`. Has it not? My intention was to control the numbering display setting on an buffer basis.

Comment: No, it onlyaffects Org mode buffers, which I thought is what you wanted, but I was mistaken. See my answer for a per-file solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following `local variables` section to the end of any Org mode file where you want `display-line-numbers-mode` to be enabled. Adding it as a COMMENT section makes sure that Org mode ignores it:

```
...
* COMMENT File local variables
Local Variables:
eval: (display-line-numbers-mode 1)
End:
```

Make sure that this is the last section in the file at the very bottom. See [Specifying File variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) in the Emacs manual. After adding the section, save and kill the buffer and reopen it in order to have the Local Variables settings take effect.

Comment: “*save and kill the buffer and reopen*” --- `revert-buffer` also works well in my Emacs.

Comment: So does `M-x normal-mode` - there are many ways to do that.